# Extract cbb file with flopy, but the output file is empty

Tags: python, flopy

I used the code to read cbb file, and tried to extract data in a new txt file. But the program completes very quickly and the output txt file is empty.

```
import flopy

cbb_file = r'D:\ZFZ\TBW_Project\IHM_Sim\IHM\IHM_input\Calibration\MODFLOW\gv37.cbb'

cbb = flopy.utils.CellBudgetFile(cbb_file)
times = cbb.get_times()

output_file_baseflow = r'D:\ZFZ\TBW_Project\IHM_Sim\IHM\IHM_input\Calibration\MODFLOW\baseflow.txt'  

with open(output_file_baseflow, 'w') as file:
   
    file.write("Text Entry, Time, Row, Column, Layer, Flow Data\n")

    for time_step, time in enumerate(times):
        baseflow_data = cbb.get_data(totim=time)

        for layer, data in enumerate(baseflow_data):
            for row, cols in enumerate(data):
                for col, baseflow in enumerate(cols):
                    file.write(f"{baseflow['text']}, {time}, {layer}, {row}, {col}, {baseflow['q']}\n")

print(f"Flow data with layers saved to {output_file_baseflow}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify that the size of the cbb file is as expected?  If it is the expected size, can you experiment with the optional `precision` argument to see if that will get the reader to appropriately process the binary records?

Comment: Thank you for your response. The size of the cbb file is 325 MB.  I used Groundwater Vistas to do the simulation, and I used flopy to read the cbb file which showed data matrix in Pycharm outcome window, but can't output any data in txt file. Then I used  Hex Editor Neo to open the cbb file which indeed proves there is data in the cbb file. Thank you.